# Executing arcpy.createTable_management with parameters from arcpy.GetParameterAsText?

Tags: arcpy, parameters, error-999999

I'm trying to create a script tool in ArcMap that creates an attachment match table.  The script fails giving this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\py\PhotoMatch_test.py", line 40, in <module>
arcpy.CreateTable_management(outputGdb, matchTable)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 14419, in CreateTable
raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (CreateTable).
```

My code looks like this:

```
import arcpy, sys

inputFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
picfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
matchTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

outputGdb = arcpy.env.scratchGDB
arcpy.CreateTable_management(outputGdb, matchTable)
```

The parameter properties of the script tool:
[image]

I'm obviously a beginner.

Comment: The parameters in the script tool need to be in the same order(/index?) as they appear in the script. So move the parameter 'Input features' to the top using the arrows to the right

Answer (score 3):

The parameters in the script tool need to be in the same order(/index?) as they appear in the script. So move the parameter `Input features` to the top using the arrows to the right.

Also from what i can see in your code you are not using the `picfolder` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was bad parameters passed to arcpy.CreateTable_management.  I needed a path and a name, but I had given two full paths, which may not have even matched.  Here's the change:

```
outputGdb = os.path.dirname(matchTable)
arcpy.CreateTable_management(outputGdb, os.path.basename(matchTable))
```

Comment: `arcpy.CreateTable_management(*os.path.split(matchTable))` is pretty simple.